# Close In/OutputStream in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

As u can see, i did close the the *fo* and *oo*, so after that do i need to close the *OutputStream* ? :

```
public void writedata(List<sinhvien> svlist) {
    FileOutputStream fo = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oo = null;
    try {
        fo = new FileOutputStream(datasv);
        oo = new ObjectOutputStream (fo);
        oo.writeObject(svlist);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}
    
    finally {
            try {
                fo.close();
                oo.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e ) {}
    }
}
```

Somethings like : ... **OutputStream** *os*
**if** (*os* != null ) **try** { *os*.close() } ...
Is this necessary ?

Comment: 1, you should use try-with-resources 2, calling `close` on `ObjectOutputStream` will also close underlying `OutputStream`

Comment: If the class implements `AutoCloseable` or `Closeable` and it is initialized then it can and should be closed (unless using try-with-resources with `AutoCloseable` interface). This could simply be found by searching each class and checking the documentation. Hence, downvoting the question.

Comment: However in your case you are embedding one stream into another hence when you close one you are closing the underlying stream.

Comment: Thank u all, guys !! I got it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it in the wrong order.

streams are allowed to buffer. By closing the underlying stream (`fo`) first, if `oo` buffered, your code fails. You are also eating any exceptions which is obviously an extremely bad idea: If your code fails (for example, that `oo` close throws an exception, reporting that it failed to write out the last few bytes because fo is already closed, you'd never know, and now you have a corrupt file and no idea that it is corrupted.

You could just close `oo` and be done with it, but the problem is, what if `oo = new ObjectOutputStream(fo)` fails? You'd still need to close `fo` then.

The lessons:

1. You have to close each resource that you open, in stack order (the last thing you made needs to be closed first).
2. Do not, ever, write an empty catch block unless you really, really, *really* know what you are doing.

The best way to apply these lessons:

1. Use try-with-resources
2. Freely litter `throws IOException` and the like on your signatures. your `main` should be declared as `throws Exception`. Where not feasible or possible, the right 'I do not know what happened' catch block is: `catch (Thingie e) { throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e);

Thus:

```
public void writedata(List<sinhvien> svlist) throws IOException {
    try (var fo = new FileOutputStream(datasv);
         var oo = new ObjectOutputStream(fo)) {

        oo.writeObject(svlist);
    }
}
```

is orders of magnitude better:

1. It doesn't suffer from caching issues
2. It is much easier to read and follow
3. a method called 'writeData' can obviously exit in the alternate way of: Hmm, whoops, issues with the I/O system that I'm saving it to. methods should throw what seems obvious, and IOException is obvious here.
4. does not silently do nothing when saving the data fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try with a resource and do away with explicit close calls
Something like

```
public void writeData(final List<Sinhvein> svList){
    try(final FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(datasv); final ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);){
    // do something with fo and oo
    }
}
```

the whole point of having a try with the resource is to avoid explicit finally blocks which take care of clean up.

Comment: So u mean : just simply add *final* and no need to *close* anything at all ?

Comment: no, final is just a qualifier to make sure that the variable is not bound to another object. enclosing the initialization within the try itself will take care of closing the resources opened

Comment: Ok, I got it. I've just read "try with resources" in docs.oracle..

Comment: Anyway, if i keep using that my old way, do u think i need to *close* the *OutputStream* ? Or just closing the  *fo* and *oo* is enough ?